# wedged - partial install of viking-gps

Tags: software-center, uninstall

On Ubuntu 17.10 I attempted an install of viking-gps through Ubuntu Software Center. At the end, it indicated a failed install, mentioning something about a dropped connection.

The app is damaged and will not run. A couple of methods to uninstall haven't worked. The app doesn't show up under the "installed" tab in the Ubuntu Software Center window and it doesn't show up with dpkg --list.

When I do a search in Ubuntu Software Center, the program is still found, but when I click "Install" it refuses to reinstall saying the program is already installed.

How I got it from the software center: In the dock on the left of the desktop there is an icon that looks like an orange shopping bag with a big capital "A" on it. I click on that. On the window that pops up, there is a looking glass in the upper right corner. I click on that and type in "viking" to the search term entry box that appears at the top of the window. An icon for viking-gps appears along with a title and an "install" button. I click on that button to install

What is the best way to recover and install a working program?

There were a number of messages mentioning snap and snapd, but I don't understand those at all.

After a number of tries, it did install, but it would fail with the message: "Desktop file didn't specify Exec field"

dgktkr

Comment: There is no package called 'viking-gps' in the Ubuntu repositories. Please edit your question to explain how you got it to appear in Software Center.

Comment: You're right, it's not there now. It was there 2 hours ago. Did it get taken down because it had issues?

Comment: Aha, seems like you installed the snap package: https://uappexplorer.com/snap/ubuntu/viking-gps . Try `snap list` to confirm that the viking-gps snap is installed. If the viking-gps snap is installed, try `snap-remove` to uninstall it. If the uninstall fails, copy-and-paste the entire snap session into your question - the error messages tell us a lot of useful information.

Comment: "snap list" showed it installed. "snap remove viking-gps" succesfully uninstalled it. Now, even with a successful reinstall, I get an error "Desktop file didn't specify Exec field" if started from the GUI and fails to find a Mapnik shared library if started from the command line. It looks like this is a question for the developer(s) of the app, not Ubuntu folks. Thanks for the help.